# Not really addition

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

```
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 4 = 3
16 + 4 = 11
4 + 4 = 7
5 + 4 = 6
5 + 2 = 10
6 + 2 = 10
2 + 2 = 7
8 + 10 = 5
4 + 10 = 4
5 + 10 = 4
3 + 10 = 5
81 + 7 = ?
```

**Hint**

> $10 + 1 \ne 1 + 10$

**Hint 2**

> The number four

What is the pattern? What is 81 + 7? How are the results calculated?

Comment: Question is 2+2 actually equal to 7?

Comment: I suggest using a non mathematical symbol instead of + to make this puzzle less confusing. Maybe @? 1 @ 2 = 3, 1 @ 4 = 3, etc.

Comment: @MMAdams Possibly, but I did make it pretty clear

Comment: @Goinghamateur Maybe :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

> 81+7= 11
>  81's base 7 representation is 144. Which is onefourfour, which is 11 letters long.
>  81-49 = 32  (1) ->3
>  32-28 = 4   (4) ->4
>  4 = 4 (4) - > 4
>  3+4+4 = 11

Explanation:

> take the first number, put it in the base of the second number, and count the number of letters in the representation.

How I got it:

> The ? + 10 = ? numbers gave it away for me. 8 is 5 letters, 4 is 4 letters, 5 is 4 letters, 3 is 5 letters.